# Why won't this Namespace naming convention work with my Enum?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Here is my Enums.cs file that exists in a CPSLibrary Class Library:

```
namespace CPSLibrary.CPSEnums
{
    public enum GoalType
    {
        STRATEGIC = 1,
        TACTICAL = 2
    }
}
```

In a code behind file within a web application that references CPSLibrary, I'm doing the following:

```
using CPSLibrary;

/*  ... farther down the page ... */
proj.Goal == CPSLibrary.CPSEnums.GoalType.STRATEGIC;
```

That will work, but if I try to just reference it like CPSEnums.GoalType.STRATEGIC it won't.  Additionally, if I add "using CPSLibary.CPSEnums" I can then reference it simply as GoalType.STRATEGIC.

What do I need to do to get this to recognize CPSEnums.GoalType.STRATEGIC ?

Oddly enough, other classes with the CPSLibrary Class Library can reference it as CPSEnums.GoalType.STRATEGIC just fine.

Bonus Question: in this example, does "CPSEnums" have a technical term?  "Container" or something like that?  Or is it just a part of the Namespace with no separate terminology?

TIA

Comment: Why would you wanna write `CPSEnums.GoalType.STRATEGIC` instead of `GoalType.STRATEGIC`? That's 9 keystrokes more!

Comment: Just a personal quirk, I guess - On certain things (such as Enums) I like seeing some of the "organization" right in the code without hovering over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your using statement to this...

```
using CPSEnums = CPSLibrary.CPSEnums;
```

This should allow you to reference it the way you want...

```
/*  ... farther down the page ... */
proj.Goal == CPSEnums.GoalType.STRATEGIC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your namespace name is `CPSLibrary.CPSEnums`, so you can even write like:

```
using CPSLibrary.CPSEnums;
....
proj.Goal == GoalType.STRATEGIC; //NO NAMESPACE NAME
```

when you write `using CPSLibrary`, you refer to the  "parent" namespace of your defined one. This is perfectly valid. But to access *your* enum type, you need specify *its* namepsace, and *its* namespace is: `CPSLibrary.CPSEnums`

Comment: I considered that would be the likely answer but it doesn't explain why the structure is retained within the Class Library itself but then it appears to get flattened upon being compiled.  If I'm in a different class in the CPSLibrary namespace, I can use CPSEnums to get to GoalType but I can't go to GoalType directly without a reference to CPSEnums.  If it truly was a separate Namespace then I'd need a using CPSLibrary.CPSEnums in order to get to GoalType.  There it works as a "folder-esque" structure but that all goes away once it's compiled?  Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
namespace CPSLibrary
{
    public static class CPSEnums
    {
        public enum GoalType
        {
            STRATEGIC = 1,
            TACTICAL = 2
        }
    }
}


var x = CPSEnums.GoalType.STRATEGIC;
```